# Sagas Pattern with Kafka and Masstransit

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, masstransit

I've been using Kafka and Masstransit for a few days and just stumble upon the Sagas Pattern. I'm thinking of applying this pattern to my app but I'm not sure whether or not Masstransit supports Sagas for Kafka.

I say this because most of the Sagas examples that I could find on the Masstransit docs were applied to RabbitMQ and I know Kafka and RMQ work a bit differently.

Comment: Sagas work fine with Kafka.

Comment: Have you tried it? What issues are you running into?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't try anything yet! I was just trying to see if Kafka is supported by Masstransit/Sagas before apply the pattern. As I said, I couldn't find many resources or implementations of Sagas with Kafka.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Glad to hear that! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Masstransit actually provides a great support when it comes to the sagas pattern. I was able to explore some of the resources provided by the package through a POC.

Here as an [application demo](https://github.com/Igor03/kafka-sagas-demo) coupling everything together.

I'm sure that still have a lot to explore, tho! :)